# ESLint,prettier и VS Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, package, eslint

После установки пакетов npm install eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-prettier prettier lint-staged husky --save-dev.  Создания соответствующих файлов конфигурации  .eslintrc и  .prettierrc   в корне проекта при запуски команды npm run eslint и установки плагинов из маркета VS code. В терминале ошибка

```
:npm ERR! missing script: eslint

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Евгений\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-16T14_07_00_742Z-debug.log
```

А при запуске вот этой команды node_modules/.bin/eslint src/
терминал выдаёт  что 'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. (данная папка тоже в корне с проектом )

.prettierrc

{ "userTabs": false,
        "printWidth": 80,
        "tabWidth":2,
        "singleQuote":true,
        "trailingComma":"es5",
        "parcer":"flow",
        "semi":false
    }

.eslintrc

```js
{
"extends": [
    "react-app",
    "prettir"
],

"rules" : {

    "jsx-quotes": [
        1,
        "prefer-double"
    ]

    },
    "plugins":[
        "prettier"
    ]
}
```

Короче линтер не запускается.. потому что я криворукий) помогите)..Скрин pacage.json    я приложил [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Для работы `eslint-plugin-prettier` ещё необходимо отдельно ставить ESLint: `npm i -D eslint`. Это написано в readme на github:

> eslint-plugin-prettier does not install Prettier or ESLint for you.
>   You must install these yourself.

Также у вас опечатка в конфигурационном файле `.eslintrc.json`: prettir -> prettier.

`npm run eslint`. Эта команда запускает скрипты, которые были описаны в файле package.json, если его там нет, то оно будет выдавать ошибку `missing script: eslint`. Т.е. нужно добавить, что-то подобное:

```
"scripts": {
  "eslint": "eslint --format codeframe ./"
},
```

Ну и вообще, полезно было бы просмотреть документацию плагинов, там есть описание и примеры, как настраивать и пользоваться.

Comment: Да,видимо стоило почитать про плагины.. С ходу по туториалу учебного проекта.. нормально ничего не заработало